# Sales Cloud Event Pushed Immediately to Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions

I need to have a data extension in Marketing Cloud that has real-time data. I need the Data Extension to be updated immediately if someone purchases a ticket. I know that I can query for this in Automation Studio hourly, but I need it immediately. I was thinking there may be a way to 'push' that data from Sales Cloud when it happens. Query activities 'pull' it in from Sales Cloud, but is there a way to 'push' it from Sales Cloud when it happens? I thought maybe Contact Builder was my friend here, but I have not figured out a way to do it.

Comment: Set up an apex trigger in SalesCloud to fire an Marketing cloud api,. You can either use the SOAP or REST

Comment: HMMM I'm afraid that may be beyond my team, but I'll suggest it, thanks!

Comment: What edition do you use? If you have Journey Builder you can accomplish something like this. API, however, would be more suited to simple data synchronization.

Comment: If you dont mind 15 mins sync you can also use data synchronization. Store your event in an SF object and synchronize them

Comment: For the API you can get pointers from here : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/200593/making-a-callout-in-apex-to-marketing-cloud-soap-api

Comment: @StephandePaly not sure..

Comment: @Data_Kid the 15 mins sync would work, what is data synchronization? I have synchronized data extensions, but I can't figure out how to get those to map to just a regular data extension I can use in Contact Builder. As for the API, I'm familiar and my SF team could do it, but it's a lot of work, so rather not go that route

Comment: What could also work is if I can have them exit a journey into another journey, but I haven't been able to figure that out