# Retrieve Email Templates from Marketing Cloud using Apex

Tags: marketing-cloud

i'm trying to get the Email Templates from SFMC using Apex. I understand that the SOAP Api of SFMC has to be used but i don't know how to call it to retrieve the email templates.
By the way, I try this example to connect to SFMC using SOAP:
[Making a callout in Apex to Marketing Cloud SOAP API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/200593/making-a-callout-in-apex-to-marketing-cloud-soap-api)
and it works great.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [SOAP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_an_email_via_the_soap_api.htm) to retrieve email from Classic Tool:

```xml
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Header>
    <fueloauth>YOUR_TOKEN_HERE</fueloauth>
</Header>
<Body>
    <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>Email</ObjectType>
            <Properties>ID</Properties>
            <Properties>Name</Properties>
            <Properties>Subject</Properties>
            <Properties>Status</Properties>
            <Properties>PartnerKey</Properties>
            <Properties>CreatedDate</Properties>
            <Properties>Folder</Properties>
            <Properties>CategoryID</Properties>
            <Properties>EmailType</Properties>
            <Properties>HTMLBody</Properties>
            <Properties>ContentAreas</Properties>
            <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
                <Property>Id</Property>
                <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
                <Value>{EMAIL_ID_HERE}</Value>
            </Filter>
        </RetrieveRequest>
    </RetrieveRequestMsg>
</Body>
```

**Remove filter part to retrieve all emails or filter by CategoryId as @pkharries suggested**

ID can be found in email properties.
[image: classic content id]


---


Use [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/routes.htm#detail_getObjectById) to retrieve email from Content Builder:

```json
https://www.exacttargetapis.com/asset/v1/content/assets/{id}

GET /asset/v1/content/assets/{EMAIL_ID_HERE} HTTP/1.1
Host: www.exacttargetapis.com
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_TOKEN_HERE
Content-Type: application/json
```

**Or retrieve all assets (filter by name for example):**

```
GET /asset/v1/content/assets?$filter=Name%20like%20'Template' 
HTTP/1.1
Host: www.exacttargetapis.com
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_TOKEN_HERE
Content-Type: application/json
```

ID can be found in email properties.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this example is for retrieve one specific Email Template, isn't it? I want to retrieve all the Email Templates from SFMC, it's that possible? I also don't see where to find de Email id. Regards

Comment: @Alvaro By Using CategoryId  of Email Folder  you can Retrieve All Emails At a time  use like this in filter part  <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
                <Property>CategoryID</Property>
                <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
                <Value>61324</Value>
            </Filter>

Comment: Or just remove Filter part from the request

Comment: @Alvaro please check updated answer with additional information for retrieving list of emails

Comment: Great answer @matrosik, i can retrieve the email templates with the examples given! Thank you very much

Comment: @Ros Haitovich are you still having problems with the retrievement of email templates?

Comment: You asked about templates not me :)