# In regards to Unsubscribe a subscribers from sales cloud without using MC Connector

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I am new to Salesforce Marketing Cloud and I have question in regards to Salesforce Marketing Cloud Connector , What can be the process of unsubscribing the subscriber from sales cloud without using Marketing Cloud Connector setting . Can this be achieved using API's or Apex coding from Sales cloud?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible through API using Apex, but it will be so much easier done if you implement Marketing Cloud Connect - really not worth the time developing web API calls, when you have the whole Marketing Cloud Connect package ready.

If you'd like to look into API for managing unsubscribes anyway, the object you need to update using the SOAP API is the Subscriber object: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/subscriber.htm

In regards to using SOAP API from an Apex Trigger, take a look here: [Making a callout in Apex to Marketing Cloud SOAP API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/200593/making-a-callout-in-apex-to-marketing-cloud-soap-api)