# SFMC SOAP API Internal server error

Tags: apex, marketing-cloud, soap-api

Am new to SOAP and newer to SFMC SOAP API.
I am trying to retrieve DE rows via SOAP API and couple of questions, as I keep hitting a 500 error - internal server error.

My code is below - first question - does the request envelope format look ok? To me it aligns to what is required and what I have seen elsewhere.  Second question - have I got the request itself set ok? I cant find what should be put in the SOAPAction header param.

Any pointers would be really appreciated. Im not finding this API particularly easy to figure out..

```
public with sharing class SfmcSoapIntegration {

// from https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/200593/making-a-callout-in-apex-to-marketing-cloud-soap-api

private static String makeHTTPXMLPost(String endPoint, String soapBody){
    Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest r = new HttpRequest();
    r.setTimeout(60000);
    r.setEndpoint(endPoint);  
    r.setMethod('POST');
    r.setHeader('SOAPAction',WONDERING_WHAT_SHOULD_GO_HERE_FOR_DE_QUERY?); 
    r.setHeader('Accept','text/xml');  
    r.setHeader('Content-type','text/xml');    
    r.setHeader('charset','UTF-8'); 
    r.setBody(soapBody);    
    HttpResponse s = h.send(r);
    return s.getBody();
}

// from https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/200593/making-a-callout-in-apex-to-marketing-cloud-soap-api

public static String performMCRetrieveData(String recordId, String dataExtensionName ){
    String soapEnvelopeTemplate =
    '<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">'+
    '       <Header>'+
    '          <Security xmlns="https://www.marketingcloud.com/">'+
    '             <fueloauth>{0}</fueloauth>'+
    '          </Security>'+
    '       </Header>'+
    '       <Body>'+
    '          <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">'+
    '             <RetrieveRequest>'+
    '                <ObjectType>DataExtensionObject[{1}]</ObjectType>'+
    '                <Properties>CurrentTier</Properties>'+
    '                   <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">'+
    '                   <Property>CurrentTier</Property>'+
    '                   <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>'+
    '                   <Value>1</Value>'+
    '                </Filter>'+
    '             </RetrieveRequest>'+
    '          </RetrieveRequestMsg>'+
    '       </Body>'+
    '    </Envelope>';


    SfmcRestApi restApi = new SfmcRestApi();
    String accessToken = restApi.getAccessToken();

    String body = String.format(soapEnvelopeTemplate, 
                                new String[]{ accessToken, dataExtensionName  });
    return makeHTTPXMLPost('https://MYSERVER.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx' , body );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was that the xml payload header as shown below was wrong -- the Security tags are not required around the fueloauth tags. Once they were removed the 500 error was resolved.

```
'   <Security xmlns="https://www.marketingcloud.com/">'+
'             <fueloauth>{0}</fueloauth>'+
'   </Security>'+
```